# What hash algorithms are most suitable for generating unique IDs in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, hash

I have a large geospatial data set (~30m records) which I am currently importing into a PostgreSQL database.  I need a unique ID to assign to each record, but an incrementing integer might be a bad idea because it could not be reliably recreated if I ever needed to reimport the data set.

It seems that a unique hash of the geometry data in a determined projection might be the best option for a reliable identifier.  Being able to calculate the hash within Postgres would be beneficial, and speed would also be of benefit.

What is/are my options given this situation?  Is there a particular method that is highly suitable for this situation?

Comment: Do you mean a unique, stable identifier you can *recreate* from the data itself, or just a globally unique identifier which is guaranteed never to clash with anything? \*cough\*`uuid`\*cough\*

Comment: Recreate from the data itself.  UUID would change if I had to reload the data for some reason.

Comment: md5? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Sure, md5 is popular and that's the first one I thought of too.  If that's the most suitable option ([which it may be](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgcrypto.html#AEN137703)), then I'm looking for some justification on that so I don't overlook a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a unique identifier that depends on (and can be recreated from) the data, the most straightforward option seems to be a [MD5](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) hash, which is included in Posgresql (no need of additional libraries) and is quite efficient and -for this scenario- secure.

The [pgcrypto module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgcrypto.html) provides additional hashing algorithms, eg SHA1.

Of course, you need to assert that the data to be hashed is unique.